# Who to the number of users who have had one transaction per day?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
select count(1) from 
    (select count(1) num, user_id from pos_transactions pt 
    where date(created_at) <= '2020-6-21'
    group by user_id  
    having num = 1) x
```

It gives me the number of users who have had 1 transaction until `2020-6-21`. Now I want to group it also per `date(created_at)`. I mean, I want to get a list of dates (such as `2020-6-21`, `2020-6-22` etc ..) plus the number of users who have had 1 transaction in that date (day).

Any idea how can I do that?

---

**EDIT:** The result of query above is correct, the issue is, it's manually now. I mean, I have to increase `2020-6-21` by hand. I want to make it automatically. In other words, I want a list of all dates (from `2020-6-21` til now) contains the number of users who have had 1 transaction until that date.

Comment: Pls follow this guidance to improve your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: why don't you add `date(created_at)` to GROUP BY list  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of users who had one transaction on each day, then you need to aggregate by the date as well:

```
select dte, count(*)
from (select date(created_at) as dte, user_id
      from pos_transactions pt 
      where date(created_at) <= '2020-6-21'
      group by dte, user_id  
      having count(*) = 1
     ) du
group by dte;
```